# How does a pointer to a Base class which initialized by a derived class can have *__vptr called the right virtual function?

Tags: c++, vtable, dynamic-dispatch, virtual-table

Would someone please explain to me *the bold parts*?

I didn't get how come *__vptr which is in the Base portion of the class and dPtr has access to this pointer CAN all of a sudden point to the D1 virtual table instead of the Base virtual table!
I have read some articles, watched some sources and still confused.

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void function1() {};
    virtual void function2() {};
};
 
class D1: public Base
{
public:
    virtual void function1() {};
};
 
class D2: public Base
{
public:
    virtual void function2() {};
};
int main()
{
    D1 d1;
    Base *dPtr = &d1;
 
    return 0;
}
```

Note that because dPtr is a base pointer, it only points to the Base portion of d1. However, also note that *__vptr is in the Base portion of the class, so dPtr has access to this pointer. ***Finally, note that dPtr->__vptr points to the D1 virtual table!*** Consequently, even though dPtr is of type Base, ***it still has access to D1’s virtual table (through __vptr).***

Source: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/125-the-virtual-table/comment-page-6/#comment-484189

Comment: The vptr is stored in base class, but each subclass constructor initializes it to point to vtable of that particular class.

Comment: Note that "To implement virtual functions, C++ uses a special form of late binding known as the virtual table." is just wrong. C++ has no virtual table. C++ has inheritance and virtual functions and overriding. Using a virtual table is the common way to implement that, but in principle nothing would change on how inheritance, virtual functions and overriding works if there was no virtual table, its an implementation detail

Comment: It doesn't happen "all of a sudden". It happens in the correct, logical place: the derived ctor.

Comment: ps: I am not saying that your question is not a good question, but too often what is specified is confused with implementation details. If you want to understand virtual functions, knowing about the virtual table surely helps, but it is not necessary

Comment: I am still confused that if dPtr is a base pointer and only points to the Base portion of d1 and *__vptr is in the Base portion of the class and dPtr has access to this pointer, then dPtr->__vptr should point to Base virtual table NOT D1 virtual table.

Comment: But `dPtr` is pointing to the `Base` portion of a `D1` object. That's why the vptr is pointing to a `D1` vtable.

Comment: @Kevin Thank you. It makes sense now. So when we instantiate this d1 object. It consists of two portion: Base and D1. Each of those has its own *__vptr pointer and for the Base portion of d1, *__vptr points to the (func2)Base virtual function and for the D1 portion of d1, *__vptr points to the (func1). is that correct?

Comment: No, there's one vptr, and the `D1` ctor sets it to point at the `D1` vtable, so after construction even pointers-to-`Base` are pointing at an object that refers to a `D1` vtable. And if there was a further subclass, its constructor would set the vptr to its vtable, etc. etc.

Comment: @underscore_d Thank you so much. Now I understand it and it feels so good. When d1 is instantiated , *__vptr as its member is initialized by the constructor of D1 with its virtual table and this dPtr has access to this *__vptr of object d1 although  this dPtr  points to the Base portion of the D1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) you need to understand that the implementation of C++ is not the definition of C++.

C++ is defined by the behavior of an abstract machine.  This abstract machine's behavior is defined by the standard, and a compliant C++ compiler must compile programs to run *as-if* they ran on that abstract machine.

The rules of what that abstract machine does are inspired and based off of real computers and real implementations of C++ and C programs.

So when you talk about "virtual function tables", you are talking about **one common implementation** of what C++ does with virtual methods.  That common implementation doesn't define how C++ acts, and mixing the two up can cause problems.

---

That being said, C++'s virtual methods where based off of doing basically the exact same thing in C.  It can help to sketch out how virtual methods and inheritance would work in C++ if you re-implemented it.  (this has practical use, because doing so lets you make a custom object model, and custom object models let you do certain things more efficiently that the C++ object model would).

```
struct Bob_vtable {
  void(*print)(Bob const*) = 0;
};

struct Bob {
  Bob_vtable const* vtable = 0;
  int x = 0;

  // glue code to dispatch to vtable:
  void print() const {
    return vtable->print(this);
  }
  
  // implementation of Bob::print:
  static void print_impl( Bob const* self ) {
    std::cout << self->x;
  }

  // vtable helpers:
  static Bob_vtable make_vtable() {
    return { &Bob::print_impl };
  }
  static Bob_vtable const* get_vtable() {
    static const Bob_vtable retval = make_vtable();
    return &retval;
  }
  Bob():vtable(get_vtable()) {}
};
```

here is a really simple, no inheritance, implementation of a class `Bob` with a single virtual method `print`.  It roughly corresponds to:

```
class Bob {
public:
  int x = 0;
  virtual void print() const { std::cout << x; }
};
```

you can see why it is nice to have all of this glue code written for you.

When you do this:

```
class Alice : public Bob {
public:
  int y = 0;
  void print() const override { std::cout << x << "," << y; }
};
```

the "manual implementation" would look someting like:

```
struct Alice : Bob {
  int y = 0;

  // no print glue code needed(!)

  // implementation of Alice::print:
  static void print_impl( Bob const* bobself ) {
    Alice const* self = static_cast<Alice const*>(bobself);
    std::cout << self->x << "," << self->y;
  }

  static Bob_vtable make_vtable() {
    Bob_vtable bob_version = Bob::make_vtable();
    bob_version.print = &Alice::print_impl;
    return bob_version;
  }
  static Bob_vtable const* get_vtable() {
    static const Bob_vtable retval = make_vtable();
    return &retval;
  }

  Alice():Bob() {
    // after constructing Bob, replace the vtable with ours:
    vtable = get_vtable();
  }
};
```

and there you have it.

Take a look at what happens here:

```
Alice a;
a.print(std::cout);
```

now, `a.print` actually calls `Bob::print`, because `Alice` has no `print` method.

`Bob.print` does this:

```
  void print() const {
    return vtable->print(this);
  }
```

it grabs the vtable pointer **of this object instance**, and calls the print function in it.

What is the vtable pointer of an object of type `Alice`?  Look at the `Alice` constructor.

First it default-constructs `Bob` (which sets `vtable` to point at `Bob`'s vtable), but then it does this:

```
    vtable = get_vtable();
```

this call to `get_vtable` calls `Alice::get_vtable`:

```
    static const Bob_vtable retval = make_vtable();
    return &retval;
```

which in turn calls `Alice::make_vtable`:

```
    Bob_vtable bob_version = Bob::make_vtable();
    bob_version.print = &Alice::print_impl;
    return bob_version;
```

which first calls `Bob`'s `make_vtable`, then replaces `.print` with the `Alice::print_impl`.

So `Bob::print` calls `vtable->print(this)`, which is `Alice::print_impl(this)`, which does:

```
    Alice const* self = static_cast<Alice const*>(bobself);
    std::cout << self->x << "," << self->y;
```

While `this` is a `Bob const*` at this point, it is pointing at an `Alice` object, so that `static_cast` is valid.

So we print `x` and `y` from `Alice`.

Now, here `Alice`'s vtable type is `Bob_vtable` because she didn't add any new methods.  If she added new methods, she would have an `Alice_vtable` that inherited from `Bob_vtable`, and would have to `static_cast<Alice_vtable const*>(vtable)` to access them.

This isn't quite exactly what [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) does "under the hood", but it is about as logically identical as I can write "off the cuff".  There are a myriad of different details, like the calling convention of the functions in the vtable is different, and the format of the vtable in memory doesn't match that, etc.

---

Now, in the 'manual implementation' I did use inheritance.  So that isn't C; but the inheritance in the 'manual implementation' is not doing anything object oriented.

```
struct A {int x;}; 
struct B:A{int y;};
```

is just doing

```
struct A {
  int x;
}; 
struct B {
  A base;
  int y;
};
```

with a bit of syntactic glitter on top.

The "manual implementation" is nearly 1:1 on how you would implement this (and people do) in [c](/questions/tagged/c).  You would move the methods out of the class, call them `void Bob_print(Bob const*)` instead of `void Bob::print() const`.  And you'd use `struct Alice { Bob base; int y; }` instead of `struct Alice:Bob{ int y; };`.  But the difference is almost completely syntax, not anything else.

When [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) was originally developed, OO-based C existed, and one of C++'s first goals was to be able to write C-with-classes without having to write all of the above boilerplate.

Now, C++'s object model **does not require** the above implementation.  In fact, relying on the above implementation can result in ill-formed programs or undefined behavior.  But understanding one possible way to implement C++'s object model has some use; plus, once you know how to implement C++'s object model, you can use different object models in C++.

Note that in modern C++, I'd use a lot more templates above to remove some of the boilerplate.  As a practical use, I've used similar techniques to implement augmented `std::any`'s with duck-typed virtual methods.

The result is you can get this syntax:

```
auto print = poly_method<void(Self const*, std::ostream&)>{
  [](auto const*self, std::ostream& os){ os << *self; }
};
poly_any<&print> x = 7;
x->*print(std::cout);
```

(don't try this at home).